# JPA Search by entity Object

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way using JPA (hibernate) to search the table easyily by an entity object?
I'm using a search formula with all the atributes of the entity object.
So i creat a Searchobject which contains the values entered. The other values remain null. Is there a way to search for an object that matches all those values (but ignoring the null values) in the specific table?
Or do i really make it like that:

```
if(object.attribute() != null){
    ParameterExpression<Long> p = cb.parameter(Long.class,"attribute");
    criteria.add(cb.equal(object.get("attribute"), p));
}
```

for every attribute and then add it later on the same way:

```
TypedQuery<IOrderDeliverable> q = entityManager.createQuery(query);    
if(object.attribute() > 0)
    q.setParameter("attribute", object.getAttribute());
```

I'm using an oracle DB if this matters.

Comment: I think you will need to query your database table.

Comment: so something like this `@NamedQuery(name="Object.find",
              query="SELECT o FROM Object o WHERE o.attribute = :attribute and attributeTwo = :attributeTwo")` and so on? But how do i handle the null values?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26656683/2586617)

Comment: You may also use criteria for it or a dynamic [query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422715/2586617)